# Moving content from old site/domain to new

Tags: seo, domains, 301-redirect

We have two sites/blog, and now we are merging the two blogs into one blog. We move content from domain2.com to domain1.com. What should I consider when it comes to SEO. Should I move all the traffic from domain2.com to domain1.com? And then 301 redirect articles from domain2.com to matching the imported articles at domain1.com?

Comment: Yes that is correct. If articles on domain2.com has internal linking with other articles of domains2.com then you would update those links as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should merge similar posts one by one before setting-up 301 redirection and try to maintain quality and You can do 301 post-wise.

Do not merge irrelevant post or don't redirect irrelevant post.

You can also beef-up thin content to maintain quality.

If you are deleting posts then show 404 error.